# Android: The progress bar in the window's title does not display

Tags: android, progress-bar, titlebar

I have a web view to override the built-in browser and I want to show a progress indicator on the title bar.

This is the code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    currentURL = BrowserActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("currentURL");

    try {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new browserActivityClient());
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(currentURL);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Browser: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

It should work, I think, according to Android docs and other samples I saw on the net. But it doesn't, could you please tell me where am I wrong?

And another question: if sometimes later I'll choose to declare `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in the application manifest, will the progress bar show anymore or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In fact the correct code is (tested and working):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    currentURL = BrowserActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("currentURL");

    setContentView(R.layout.browser);

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);

    try {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new browserActivityClient());

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
               setProgress(progress * 100);
              if(progress == 100) {
                 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                 setProgressBarVisibility(false);
              }
           }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(currentURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Browser: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!
Note that requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); and setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); sets the spinner progress in the action bar.

Comment: so it seems that the sample code for the "more complicated sample" is pretty much bull***t at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: The sample code works if you use `activity.setProgress(progress * 100);` instead of `activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);`, as `setProgress` requires a range from 0 to 10000

Comment: progress range {0~100} setProgress range {0~10000} so we multiply by 100 to get the full range

Answer (score 16):

I got the same problem too.

Because i set the **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"**

I solve it by add a ProgressBar in the layout xml file, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
>

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3px"
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>

<WebView   
    android:id="@+id/webview"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

**In code:**

// when load url

```
progressBar.setProgress(0);
progressBar.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
```

...

// loading...progress changed

```
progressBar.setProgress(progress);
```

...

// when page finish

```
progressBar.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

C'est finish!

Answer (score 10):

I have solved the issue.

Your call to `setProgressBarVisibility()` must be in `onStart()` or `onResume()` because, before that point, it seems you are not guaranteed to have any view on which you can change a visibility.

---

For this incredible solution by Dralangus, here's some fully tested production code. Thank you so much, Dralangus!  Finally, a spinner that does not go away upon device rotation.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private static boolean showSpinner; // needs static

public void spinnerOn()
    {
    showSpinner = true;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

public void spinnerOff()
    {
    showSpinner = false;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

protected void onResume()
    {
    // solved by Dralangus http://stackoverflow.com/a/7414659/294884
    super.onResume();
    if (showSpinner)
        {
        spinnerOn();
        }
    else
        {
        spinnerOff();
        }
    }

protected void onStart()
    {
    super.onStart();
    // note, onResume is called EVEN LATER than onStart,
    // so your most reliable choice is onResume.
    // eternal thanks to Dralangus for this solution
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ... // Your code
    }
```

Comment: For `ListActivity` this is the solution Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

Seeing how some answers mix up the two progress bars, decided to add another answer

These are for the horizontal progress bar at the top

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
setProgress(intVal);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

these are for the spinner-style progress bar in the actionbar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

You don't need to request both window features, just the one for the progress type you need.

The mistake in OP's code is caling `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` having not requested `Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS` (or vice versa: calling `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()` instead of `setProgressBarVisibility()`)

Answer (score 7):

It appears that with Android 5.0 (API 21) and above `Windows.FEATURE_PROGRESS` no longer works.  Taking some hints from the response by univasity, I was able to build a progress bar similar to those in other browsers.

activity_main.xml"

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressTint="#FF29A8FF"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` allows the progress bar to float above the webview.  Setting `android:max` to 100 makes it align with the default range in the activity, so the values don't have to be converted to the default of 0-10000 otherwise used by the progress bar.  `android:visibility="gone"` makes the progress bar invisible by default.

MainActivty.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the WebView and the ProgressBar from activity_main.xml.
    final WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    // Enables JavaScript.
    mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Updates the progress bar whenever there are changes and hides it again when it completes.
    mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });

    // Makes the mainWebView handle all URLs internally instead of calling the default browser.
    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Load a sample URL.
    mainWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
}
```

Comment: To put it bluntly, I just spent around 6 hours trying to make this progress bar work and I've browsed through over 20 Q&A's here and everywhere else and this is, **the only one**, that seems to work on full screen webview. I love you for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

WebView.loadUrl is run in a native thread so setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) gets called immediately pretty much. Also if you use Theme.NoTitleBar the title bar will not be shown and since the progress bar is in the title bar it won't be shown either.

Something like this should work.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
    currentURL = BrowserActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("currentURL");

    try {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new browserActivityClient());
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
              if(progress == 100) {
                 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
              }
           }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(currentURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Browser: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am extremely new to Android development, so this may be a silly question. What do I need to import in order to use `BrowserActivity`?

Comment: @Nick, BrowserActivity is the current activity where you are implementing your code. It's the name of your activity.