# Android - Hiding TitleBar after WebView Loads

Tags: android, webview, titlebar

I currently have a WebView in an app I am working on and after each page loads in the WebView I would like to hide the TitleBar. I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092291/android-the-progress-bar-in-the-windows-title-does-not-display) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3092291/1024787) looks like it should do exactly what I want, however the TitleBar is never hidden after the page finishes loading.

The code I am using is the same as the answer I have linked to, but I have also included it bellow. I can confirm that onProgressChanged is being called and that progress does get reported as 100 when the page finishes loading, but setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) and setProgressBarVisibility(false) both seem to do nothing. I am using requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) and requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS) before I sent content.

I have tested this on Android 2.3 and 4.1 and the result is the same for both, the TitleBar is not hidden.

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100) {
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    setProgressBarVisibility(false);
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: for webview, you must have to use requestWindowFeature() before setting its content, if you set content before and then uses requestWindowFeature(), it will generate run-time error

Comment: Quote from my question: "I am using requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) and requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS) before I sent content."

Comment: I am pointing to your questions title's answer about hiding titlebar

Comment: not sure what you're getting at...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old title bar is somewhat limited in functionality. You will probably have to make your own title bar within the layout of the activity and show/hide it yourself with `setVisibility()`.

If you are using the [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) instead of the old title bar (which is what people should be doing anyways), it has `show()` and `hide()` methods you can use to do what you want.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use TitleBar, but I guess I'll just create my own. Thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend the ActionBar instead, unless you have a compelling reason not to use it.

Comment: Most devices will be pre 3.0 and for something so simple I don't really find it worthwhile to use something like ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: And in a year from now when most devices are 3.0+? I still think using the ActionBar is better, and ActionBarSherlock is actually not hard to use at all. Creating a custom title bar with the same features and writing your own accessory methods for it is a bit of a pain. I have to do it because our designers came up with something that we can't replicate with the native ActionBar, but if you have no such restrictions, I strongly recommend using it.

Comment: I agree and I would prefer only to develop for 4.1 but it will only be running on devices we own that will never see more than 2.3. It only ended up being a few lines to make my own, I only needed to deal with onProgressChanged. It also takes up much less screen real estate at only 3dip.

Answer (score 2):

I created a android web browser targeted towards android 2.3 and ran into this same problem. 
The solution is to add this line of code somewhere in your main activity.

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

make sure you put this line before your setContentView() method or your app will force close.

Comment: Using Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE seems to hide the TitleBar always, what I am hoping to do is hide it after the page has finished loading, but have it visible when the page is loading so the user can see the page load progress.

Answer (score 0):

public void onProgressChanged (WebView view, int progress) 
    {
       if(progress<100 && pb.getVisibility()==pb.Invisible)
       {
        pb.setvisibility(pb.Visible)
      }

```
 pb.setProgress(progress);
if(progress==100)
{
      pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}
```

*where pb =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.Id.progressbar);
its working correctly for me
hope you got my code simple and sweet.....